# Bluetooth SPP: is it error-free, lossless and ordered?

Tags: bluetooth, rfcomm, spp

As far as I can tell, it is built on top of RFCOMM which I know to have these properties, so it should also have them. However, I cannot find information anywhere that explicitly states this. Can someone confirm?